# Where will a plane intersecting a cone maximize the distance to inscribed spheres? (V. Arnold)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, optimization, solution-verification, conic-sections

> A cone is cut by a plane, making a closed curve.  Two spheres, each inscribed into the cone, are tangent to the plane, at points $A$ and $B$  respectively.
>
> Find the point $C$ on the cut line (i.e. the curve formed by the intersection of the cone and plane) such that $CA + CB$ is at an extrema.
>
> --Vladimir Arnold

[image]

My solution is below.  Is it correct? Is the proof rigorous, easy to follow, and well written? How could it be improved?

---

**Solution:** Let the line $AB$ intersect the cone at points $M, N$.  The points $M, N$ are the desired points.  That is, $CA + CB$ is at an extrema if and only if $C = M$ or $C = N$.

[image]

**Proof:** Consider the family of confocal ellipses with $R,S$ as foci.  For any point $G$, the quantity $GR + GS$ is fixed for all points on a particular ellipse of this family.  Thus, given an arbitrary smooth closed convex curve $\Gamma$, the points $G$ on $\Gamma$ where $GR + GS$ is an extremum are precisely the points where an ellipse of this family is tangent to $\Gamma$.

Therefore, in the given problem, $C$ is an extrema if and only if it is a point where the cut line is tangent to some ellipse with foci $A, B$.

The cut line is clearly an ellipse with major axis along the line $AB$.

[image]

Therefore, our problem becomes:

> Given a fixed ellipse $\Gamma$ whose major axes lies on line $AB$, and the family of ellipses with foci at $A, B$, at what points on $\Gamma$ will $\Gamma$ be tangent to some ellipse of this family?

[image]

Every ellipse intersects its major axis with a tangent perpendicular to this axis.  Therefore, the ellipses which intersect $M$ or $N$ will be tangent at those points.

Furthermore, there can be no other points of tangency, since as we move around an ellipse, the slope of the tangent varies strictly monotonically *(this last point seems admittedly like hand waving.*)

---

## Update

Reviewing [Dandelin spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres), it's clear that not only are the foci on the *line* $AB$, the foci are the points $A,B$! This means $MA = BN$ and my solution is wrong.  Rather, the value $CA + CB$ is constant.

If so, my question becomes: Where is the "proof" wrong?

Comment: Your proof is "wrong" because the tangent ellipse is the same as the curve. But I'd also say that the problem is misleading.